# CUDA 5.0 Replay Overhead

Tags: optimization, cuda

I am a novice CUDA programmer. I recently learned more about achieving better performance at lower occupancy. Here is a code snippet, I need help for understanding a few thing about replay overhead and Instruction Level Parallellism

```
__global__ void myKernel(double *d_dst, double *d_a1, double *d_a2, size_t SIZE) 
{

    int tId = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    d_dst[tId]            = d_a1[tId] * d_a2[tId];
    d_dst[tId + SIZE]     = d_a1[tId + SIZE] * d_a2[tId + SIZE];
    d_dst[tId + SIZE * 2] = d_a1[tId + SIZE * 2] * d_a2[tId + SIZE * 2];
    d_dst[tId + SIZE * 3] = d_a1[tId + SIZE * 3] * d_a2[tId + SIZE * 3];
}
```

This is my simple kernel, which simply multiplies two 2D array to form a third 2D array (from logical perspective) where these array are all placed as flat 1D arrays in device memory.

Below I present another piece of code snippet:

```
void doCompute() {

    double *h_a1;
    double *h_a2;

    size_t SIZE = pow(31, 3) + 1;

   // Imagine h_a1, h_a2 as 2D arrays
   // with 4 rows and SIZE Columns
   // For convenience created as 1D arrays 

    h_a1 = (double *) malloc(SIZE * 4 * sizeof(double));
    h_a2 = (double *) malloc(SIZE * 4 * sizeof(double));

    memset(h_a1, 5.0, SIZE * 4 * sizeof(double));
    memset(h_a2, 5.0, SIZE * 4 * sizeof(double));

    double *d_dst;
    double *d_a1;
    double *d_a2;

    cudaMalloc(&d_dst, SIZE * 4 * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc(&d_a1,  SIZE * 4 * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc(&d_a2,  SIZE * 4 * sizeof(double));

    cudaMemcpy(d_a1, h_a1, SIZE * 4 * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_a2, h_a2, SIZE * 4 * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int BLOC_SIZE = 32;
    int GRID_SIZE = (SIZE + BLOC_SIZE - 1) / BLOC_SIZE;

    myKernel <<< GRID_SIZE, BLOC_SIZE >>> (d_dst, d_a1, d_a2, SIZE);
}
```

Q1) Am I here breaking any coalesced memory access pattern?

Q2) Can I say that the accesses to the memory, the way they are coded in the kernel
    are also example of Instruction Level parallelism? If yes, am I using ILP2 or ILP4? And 
    Why?

Q3) If all I am doing is right then why does the nvvp profiler gives me following message?

```
Total Replay Overhead: 4.6%
Global Cache Replay Overhead: 30.3%
```

How can I reduce them or fix them?

Cheers,

Comment: Your choice of `SIZE` as a non-power-of 2 value will not give the best coalescing possibility.  But the cache should help with that.   The visual profiler should be reporting about a 50% - 60% number for global memory usage efficiency, I think. Your kernel code should present some opportunities for ILP since each line of code does not depend on the previous.  But ILP will also depend on the specific GPU you are using.  You might have different/better results if you make `SIZE` a multiple of 32, or 16.

Comment: @Robert Hi, the nature of the problem I am trying to solve doesn't allow me to have SIZE exactly the power of 2. So I improvise, I pad them with extra memory locations to make SIZE a multiple of 32. Like in this case as well, I added 1

The profiler shows that the load and store efficiency is 100%. But does that also mean, its a coalesced memory access? Does ILP applies to memory accesses as well? Threads in warp are jumping but they are not breaking 128 byte cache line? or do they? I am using doubles instead of floats? In the end if all is right here, why then the overhead?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, the SIZE value is divisible by 32, and that should be enough to give good coalescing, and so VP is reporting 100% global memory load efficiency.  ILP and coalescing are really 2 different concepts.  A code with no ILP opportunities can still have 100% bandwidth utilization, 100% coalesced, and make use of 100% of the available memory bandwidth.  Your code should be 100% coalesced.

Comment: By the way, I don't think those `memset` calls are doing what you think.  `memset` takes a `byte` quantity and sets `byte` locations.  You're taking a `double` quantity and setting every byte to 5.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. For ILP, as soon as instructions that can be independently executed are found in the code, ILP comes into play. Any dependent resource will put the warp into sleep until dependency are met and warp is scheduled for the next execution cycle, decided upon the load or how the scheduler works. Is that correct?

Last question remains what is then overhead replay? Why do I see it in this example?

Comment: aha !! the memset, my C skills are getting worse. so there is no way to only set the least significant byte to some value using memset? Or atleast I don't know of any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler has a limited ability to schedule instructions for possible ILP exploitation.  The GPU itself must also have ILP capability, and the extent of this varies by GPU generation.  Yes, any resource that is not available can cause a warp to stall, the typical one being data required from memory.  The definitions of the replay quantities you're asking about are given [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#metrics-reference).

So, for example, the global cache replay overhead will be triggered by a cache miss, and your code is going to have some cache misses.  Cache misses are possible even though you have 100% coalesced access and (nearly) 100% bandwidth utilization efficiency.